# Braintree php integration without iframe

Tags: php, braintree

I want to know if it is possible to integrate braintree payments to my website with payment form on braintree website so that it works just like paypal api (user clicks checkout, I create payment object, redirect user to paypal website, user confirms payment details, goes back to my website, website triggers payment).

If anyone curious why I need this, not all users are technologically advanced and understand iframe concept, therefore they don't feel secure to put in credit card details in a form which looks like hosted on my website.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

By design, accepting credit cards using Braintree's [Drop-in UI](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/overview/v3) or [Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview/v3) will not function the way you have described. You can always [add a Braintree badge](https://www.braintreepayments.com/badge) if you'd like to reassure your customers that the payment form is secure.

Comment: I would like to do it same as described in question due payment architecture, payment flow  and save developemnt time.